# Wooden deck butting up to retaining wall not square

Tags: repair, deck, retaining-wall

My husband built a deck from our house out toward our retaining wall.  The wall is not square with the house.
We are on a budget and want to make this aesthetically pleasing now, and will redo the retaining wall later.  Looking for some inexpensive ideas for covering the gap between the last deck board closest to the wall and the wall itself.  Virtually covering the hole between the deck and the wall and attempting to make it appear square. Thought about building a box up from the deck and half a foot over the flowerbed, to mask the uneven wall.  Would like to keep the flowerbeds but get rid of the rotten boards on the wall. Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to see just how out-of-parallel things are, but I'd seriously consider placing your furniture and furnishings and then decide if it's an issue. If you break up the visual enough, 99% of people won't even see it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table, circular, or other saw to rip the deck boards to fit.